# Border width resize automatically with browser window resize

Tags: jquery, html, css

How I can resize border-left-width and border-right-width on browser's window resize using jquery.

```
<div class="section-body"><div class="angle"></div></div>

.section-body {
    position: relative; 
}

.angle {
content: "";
display: block;
position: absolute;
bottom: 100%;
left: 0;
right: 0;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-top: 0;
border-left: 50vw solid transparent;
border-right: 50vw solid transparent;
border-bottom: 70px solid #fff;
z-index: 15;
pointer-events: none;
-moz-transform: scale(1.0001);
}
```

Comment: Get `window.width`, amend css (using .`css()`) accordingly.

Comment: can u provide full code spinet or example please.

Comment: I will when I can see your attempt, so that I can integrate my suggestion into whatever solution you already have.